# JDBC: can't send parameters from client to Derby DB by using servlet and Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I'm try to send the parameters from servlet to db and I get errors in my connection.

Steps of my works:

1. In eclipse I create a Dynamic Web Project with Tomcat server
2. Create a model (without any technology as a Spring , Hibernate, JSP, JSF and so on. ) for to use with DML methodology (clearing java code).
3. I tested the created module (by using some main test class) and it works so good (connections , inserting, deleting..).
4. After that , I can a simple HTML doc for client side.

process for running a web module step by step:

5. Before start Web project I start to run Derby DB - works OK.
6. Starting a Web project with Apache Tomcat.
7. insert data to the HTML and submitted it. - works OK
8. In the Servlet class the data gated to the doGet(...) method. - works OK.
9. From the Servlet (doGet(...) method) when I try to send the parameter to the DB I get errors in my conector class.

How can I set right that?
Thanks.

Codes:

Servlet Class:

```
@WebServlet({ "/StudentServlet", "/Student" })
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private StudentDbDao sf = new StudentDbDao();
        private Student student = new Student();

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        String studentId = request.getParameter("sudentId");
        Long id = Long.parseLong(studentId);

        String studentFullName = request.getParameter("studentFullName");

        String studentGendre = request.getParameter("studentGendre");

        String studentGrade = request.getParameter("studentGrade");

        try {
            student.setId(id);
            student.setFullName(studentFullName);
            student.setGender(studentGendre);
            student.setGrade(studentGrade);

            sf.createStudent(student);
            writer.println("The student #" + id + " inserted.");
                } catch (StudentSystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

class StudentDbDao that response for DML functionality:

```
package dao.Db;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import bean.Student;
import bean.StudentSystemException;
import dao.StudentDao;
import dao.connector.ConnectionPool;

public class StudentDbDao implements StudentDao {

    private Connection conn;

    public StudentDbDao() {
    }

    @Override
    public void createStudent(Student student) throws StudentSystemException {

    conn = ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Students(ID, FULLNAME, GENDER, GRADE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement pstmt;

    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstmt.setLong(1, student.getId());
        pstmt.setString(2, student.getFullName());
        pstmt.setString(3, student.getGender());
        pstmt.setString(4, student.getGrade());

        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println(student.getFullName() + " created successfully");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new StudentSystemException("Failed!", e);
    } finally {
        ConnectionPool.getInstance().returnConnection(conn);
    }

    }

@Override
public void removeStudent(Student student) throws StudentSystemException {
    conn = ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
    String sql = "DELETE FROM Students WHERE ID = " + student.getId();
    PreparedStatement pstmt;

    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(student.getId() + " removed successfully.");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new StudentSystemException("Failed!", e);
    } finally {
        ConnectionPool.getInstance().returnConnection(conn);
    }
}

@Override
public Student getStudentById(long id) throws StudentSystemException {

    conn = ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID = " + id;
    Student student = new Student();
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            student.setId(rs.getLong(1));
            student.setFullName(rs.getString(2));
            student.setGender(rs.getString(3));
            student.setGrade(rs.getString(4));
        }
    // else {
    // System.out.print("Student with PID #" + id + " not exists. ");
    // }
        return student;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new StudentSystemException("Failed!", e);
    } finally {
        ConnectionPool.getInstance().returnConnection(conn);
    }

}

public long getMaxRows() throws StudentSystemException {

    conn = ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Students";
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    int count = 0;

    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        rs.next();
        count = rs.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        ConnectionPool.getInstance().returnConnection(conn);
    }

    return count;
}
}
```

class ConnectionPool where code is falls when Servlet try to set the parameters:

```
public class ConnectionPool {

// static final int MAX_CONS = 1;
private Connection myconn = null;
// private Set<Connection> connections = new HashSet<Connection>();
private static ConnectionPool instance = new ConnectionPool();
String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/StudentDB";

private ConnectionPool() {

    try {
        myconn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static ConnectionPool getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public Connection getConnection() {
    // Connection conn = myconn;
    return this.myconn;
}

public void returnConnection(Connection conn) {
    this.myconn = conn;
    // myconn.add(conn);
}

public void closeAllConnections() throws StudentSystemException {

    Connection connection = myconn;

    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new StudentSystemException("Failed to close connection: ", e);
    }

}
```

---

attached before submit and after print-screens:

before:
[image]
after:

[image]

Comment: What is the stack trace you get ?

Comment: what error do you get?  What is the HTTP URL you are using to make the request?  Have you tried printing out the contents of the parameters you get from the `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()` to make sure you're not getting null or some unexpected value?

Comment: I'm using with following url:

Comment: I'm using with following url:  http://localhost:8080/ManagementStudent/

Comment: based on your update (which should be an update to the question, not an answer) your application classloader must be able to load the JDBC driver you are using.  This can most easily get achieved by packaging your JDBC driver in the lib directory of your web app.

Comment: Do you mean a WebContent/WEB-INF/ web.xml ?

Comment: My web.xml config has; `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
 ** <display-name>ManagementStudent</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>Student.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list> **
</web-app>` Maybe I can need to set it?